# How to use HTML button tag with ASP.Net server side click event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The following link shows examples of Bootstrap Modal dialogs.  Some examples have button (e.g. Send Email).
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

If the Modal dialog is on an .aspx form, is it possible to call a method (code behind in .aspx.cs) when user clicks on a button of the modal?

I tried changing the button as follows but it didn't produce any result

```
<button type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Submit_click">Email</button>
```

That is the code in method Submit_click never fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like using **ASP.Net Server control** if possible.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
   OnClick="Submit_click" Text="Email"/>
```

If you really want to use **button** tag, you need to use **OnServerClick**

```
<button type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" 
   OnServerClick="Submit_click">Email</button>
```